# Can I marshal List<? extends BaseObject> to json with Moxy (Jersey 2.17) out of box?

Tags: json, jersey, moxy

Jersey 2.17 with Moxy.

Model:

```
@XmlType(name="product.Product")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class Product {
}

@XmlType(name="product.PaperProduct")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PaperProduct extends Product {
}

@XmlType(name="product.WoodProduct")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class WoodProduct extends Product {
}
```

Resource to find PaperProduct:

```
@GET
@Path("paperProduct")
public Response findPaperProducts() {
    List<PaperProduct> products = findService.findPaperProducts();
    GenericEntity genericEntity = new GenericEntity(products, new ParameterizedTypeImpl(List.class, PaperProduct.class));
    return Response.ok(genericEntity, responseMediaType).build();
}
```

Json result (GOOD):

```
[ {
   "@xsi:type" : "product.PaperProduct",
   "name" : "note book",
}]
```

Resource to find all products, including WoodProduct:

```
@GET
@Path("product")
public Response findAllProducts() {
    List<Product> products = findService.findProducts();
    GenericEntity genericEntity = new GenericEntity(products, new ParameterizedTypeImpl(List.class, Product.class));
    return Response.ok(genericEntity, responseMediaType).build();
}
```

Json result (Not exactly what I want):

```
[ {
   "@xsi:type" : "product.Product",
   "name" : "note book"
}, {
   "@xsi:type" : "product.Product",
   "name" : "chair"}]
```

The result I want is:

```
[ {
   "@xsi:type" : "product.PaperProduct",
   "name" : "note book"
}, {
   "@xsi:type" : "product.WoodProduct",
   "name" : "chair"}]
```

How can I get the result I want?

Comment: I'm thinking it should work the way you want if you add `@XmlSeeAlso({PaperProduct.class, WoodProduct.class})` on top of the `Product` class.